# Unable to rotate model group across actual center

Tags: three.js, 3d, webgl, blender

I am a bit new to the 3d world. I am trying to create snapchat like filter which will cover your face with models. Everything was working fine until i got the new set of models which are each a head(group of skinned meshes) which i need to rotate. Earlier the resource was just the head and rotation was working fine. But now they have started exporting the head with armature and the model is rotating fine on y axis but on x axis its rotating along the base of the armature which is not visible but somehow it is still the origin. If i go in blender and remove the skeleton from the model and reset the center it starts working fine.
But sadly the models are autoexported and we have no ability to change the models. I have already tried pivoting and translating and all the suggestions i could find on the internet. Nothing works. No matter what i do, x rotation keeps happening on this arbitrary point which is the base of the armature. I am trying to upload the images but stackoverflow keeps throwing some weird error so uploaded on google drive.

Image of model on google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gCtqplAVoXyB34PpuIyLtw7SI4dqTdVq/view?usp=drive_link

Here is the link to the model
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jHH7MLLFrHMV7qo1NJ1unP5_Qlw488NV/view?usp=drive_link

Here is the video of the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qWlo8zQywbU2E5RJaIAZHDoBOMiZzfxR/view?usp=drive_link
Y rotation is happening as expected. But x is broken. (moving my face gets the rotation values and sets them to the model. So when i look up and down the model should rotate along its center and not some arbitrary point faraway making it swing

Maybe its something very straightforward which i am missing. In blender i was able to move the origin after deleting the skeleton by literally 2 clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i was able to find a solution. Instead of trying to rotate the group on different axes, etc i just grabbed the bone of head and rotated that. Working great now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if the mesh and the armature are joined correctly. And if they are not joined, check if the object with the correct origin is the parent.

Comment: hey sorry just added more details. My uploads were failing so added them via google drive. See if it makes sense now

Comment: when you look at "Image of model on google drive" you can see that the models origin is right on the point (0, 0, 0), so your model is trying to rotate around this value. How exactly do you export the model? In which format, etc?

Comment: Iv added the model in the drive. It's gltf. When I open it in blender it's plain to see what's happening. But in three.js I am unable to delete the armature or reset the origin. Ps I don't really need the armature just as long as the head is able to rotate